Encontrar la primera aparición del valor de "ordenador" con el método index
¿Que caracter ocupa la quinta posición dentro d la sig palabra="ordenador" palabra = "ordenador" esa es la pregunta y yo hice esto en python( no se si me faltan otras cosas que poner o si esta mal lo que hice.)
palabra = " ordenador"
caracter= palabra [4]
print("El caracter en la palabra en la quinta posicion es:, caracter")


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Y cual es el problema???

El caracter está dentro de las comillas, debe estar fuera print("El caracter en la palabra en la quinta posicion es:", caracter)

lo que ocurre es que tienes un pequeño error en tu código, ya que, la variable caracter está dentro de comillas y por eso se interpreta como texto. Lo que puedes hacer es ponerla fuera de comillas o usar la f y las llaves {} para dejar la variable dentro del texto.
El código
palabra = " ordenador"
caracter= palabra [4]
print("El caracter en la palabra en la quinta posicion es:, caracter")

Posible solución
palabra = " ordenador"
caracter= palabra [4]
print(f"El caracter en la palabra en la quinta posicion es:, {caracter}")

